# php shell script doesn't wait to finish process

Tags: php, asynchronous

I'm running something like this in `php` by command line:

```
echo "first sentence";
sleep(5);
echo "second sentence";
```

When running by cmd, it print *first sentence*, after 5 seconds, print the *second sentence*. But when I'm running into web browser, it waits to finish the process. Why this happen in cmd? Any idea?

Comment: All you need to do is to call `flush()` before `sleep()` but it doesn't guarantee anything. The web server itself and any proxy along the way can wait for the entire content (or at least some amount of it) to be generated before sending it back to the client. And there is no way to persuade them to work as you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. It's good for debugging purposes:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(1);
ob_end_flush();

echo "first sentence";
sleep(5);
echo "second sentence";

ob_start();
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `ob_start()` at the end of the script? Output buffering is not involved in the process anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> When running by `cmd`, it print first sentence, after 5 seconds, print the second sentence. But when I'm running into web browser, it waits to finish the process. Why this happen in `cmd?`

It happens when you run the script using the CLI because this is what you asked for it to do. **And it works the same when it is invoked by the web server.**

The difference is that, when you run it in the terminal, there is no intermediate process. The PHP interpreter produces some output and the terminal displays it as it comes.

For optimization purposes, the web server doesn't send data back to the browser (that could be half-across the Earth) as soon as the PHP script produces it. It puts it into a buffer and send it to the browser either when the PHP script ends or when the buffer is full.

The PHP interpreter itself uses such a buffer for output.

You can force PHP to send the generated output by calling [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) (after each `echo`, for example). **However, this doesn't solve anything.**

The PHP interpreter sends the output to the webserver but the web server has its own buffering mechanism that cannot be controlled from the PHP script.
More, even if the web server sends the output back to the browser, the browser decides if it uses the data to update the already rendered page or wait until more data comes (or the connection closes).

Even more, if there are proxies between the browser and the server, they usually implement their own buffering mechanisms that cannot be persuaded in any way to flush their buffers.